Unable to inject fault using 'chaosd:jvm:stress' fault on VMware NSX #268
# java version
openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

# chaosd version
(chaosd-env) root@nsx-manager:~# chaosd version
Chaosd Version: version.Info{GitVersion:"v0.0.0-master+$Format:%h$", GitCommit:"$Format:%H$", BuildDate:"2024-03-25T06:36:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.14", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

ERROR
**(chaosd-env) root@nsx-manager:~# chaosd attack jvm stress --cpu-count 2 --pid 4034
**[2024/09/15 07:59:04.740 +00:00] [ERROR] [jvm.go:57] ["bash: line 1: bminstall.sh: command not found\n"] [error="exit status 127"] [stack="github.com/chaos-mesh/chaosd/pkg/server/chaosd.jvmAttack.Attack\n\t/__w/chaosd/chaosd/pkg/server/chaosd/jvm.go:57\ngithub.com/chaos-mesh/chaosd/pkg/server/chaosd.(*Server).ExecuteAttack\n\t/__w/chaosd/chaosd/pkg/server/chaosd/attack.go:105\ngithub.com/chaos-mesh/chaosd/cmd/attack.jvmCommandFunc\n\t/__w/chaosd/chaosd/cmd/attack/jvm.go:181\nreflect.Value.call\n\t/__t/go/1.20.14/x64/src/reflect/value.go:586\nreflect.Value.Call\n\t/__t/go/1.20.14/x64/src/reflect/value.go:370\ngo.uber.org/dig.defaultInvoker\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/dig@v1.14.1/container.go:220\ngo.uber.org/dig.(*Scope).Invoke\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/dig@v1.14.1/invoke.go:92\ngo.uber.org/fx.runInvoke\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/fx@v1.17.1/invoke.go:93\ngo.uber.org/fx.(*module).executeInvoke\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/fx@v1.17.1/module.go:174\ngo.uber.org/fx.(*module).executeInvokes\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/fx@v1.17.1/module.go:155\ngo.uber.org/fx.New\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/fx@v1.17.1/app.go:534\ngithub.com/chaos-mesh/chaosd/pkg/utils.FxNewAppWithoutLog\n\t/__w/chaosd/chaosd/pkg/utils/utils.go:27\ngithub.com/chaos-mesh/chaosd/cmd/attack.NewJVMStressCommand.func1\n\t/__w/chaosd/chaosd/cmd/attack/jvm.go:116\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:860\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:974\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\n\t/github/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:902\nmain.main\n\t/__w/chaosd/chaosd/cmd/main.go:79\nruntime.main\n\t/__t/go/1.20.14/x64/src/runtime/proc.go:250"]
Error: exit status 127

Installed the chaosd toolkit 'https://chaos-mesh.org/docs/chaosd-overview/#download-and-deploy'
and try to inject fault (jvm:stress) on VMware NSX. It failed with error.
Can someone help to fix this issue
